# Domain of function $x^{1/2}$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, functions, exponential-function, discrete-logarithms

What different of 2 function: $\sqrt{x}$ and $x^{1/2}$? Why domain of $\sqrt{x}$ is $x \ge 0$ but domain of $x^{1/2}$ is $x>0$?

Comment: They are the same function. The domain of $x^{1/2}$ is $x\geq 0$. Where ever you saw otherwise might just have a typo.

Comment: May be you'd be having, $x^{-1/2}$ which requires $x\ne0 $ and $x>0$ or just a typo as ndhanson commented

Comment: Use `$` around your formulas.

Comment: x^1/2 $= \frac{x^1}{2} = \frac{x}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The two functions are actually the **same**. Maybe you're talking about $x^{-1/2}$, whose domain is $x>0$, instead of $x^{1/2}$.